# Linear Maps - Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we tell if a linear map is a projection?
For example, how do we know that a 2x2 I matrix is a projection?

Comment: We should check whether $A=A^2$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Omg thank you... exam in a couple of hours!

Comment: A word of warning: projections don't need to be orthogonal projections. Orthogonal projections are the kinds of projections where a point is taken to the nearest point on some subspace. More general projections may not satisfy this property. If you want orthogonal projections, you want matrices $A$ such that $A = A^2$, but also $A^* = A$.

Answer (score 1):

A linear map is a *projection* if, for the corresponding matrix $A$, we have $A = A^2$. Intuitively, this means that applying the linear transformation any number of times achieves exactly the same as applying it only once. An example of this would be the linear transformation given by the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$